# How to change template in Django class based view

Tags: django, django-views, django-listview

If i have a class based view like:

```
class equipmentdashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    context_object_name = 'equipmentdashboard'
    template_name = 'equipmentdashboard.html' 
    login_url = 'login'

    def get_queryset(self):
        #some stuff
```

How can I change the `template_name` depending on a query? I want to do something like:

```
class equipmentdashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    context_object_name = 'equipmentdashboard'
    if self.request.user.PSScustomer.customerName == 'Customer X':
        template_name = 'equipmentdashboard_TL.html' 
    else:
        template_name = 'equipmentdashboard.html' 
    login_url = 'login'

    def get_queryset(self):
            #some stuff
```

But you can't access the request before the `get_queryset`.
Or maybe there is an even simpler way of achieving the same behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the [**`.get_template_names()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names), and return the template name(s) that match, so:

```
class equipmentdashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    context_object_name = 'equipmentdashboard'
    login_url = 'login'
    
    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.user.PSScustomer.customerName == 'Customer X':
            return ['equipmentdashboard_TL.html']
        else:
            return ['equipmentdashboard.html']
```

`.get_template_names()` should return an *iterable* of template names. Django will enumerate through the list if the template does not exists, and thus render the first template of the iterable that does exist. In this case we can thus return a singleton list with the only template that Django should try to render.